# Should topic created via kafka-topics automatically have associated subjects created?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I'm attempting to mimic 'confluent load' (which isn't recommended for production usage) to add the connectors which automatically creates the topic, subject, etc. that allows for ksql stream and table creation.  I'm using curl to interact with the rest interface.

1. When kafka-topics is used to create topics, does this also create the associated subjects for `"topicName-value"`, etc.?

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8082/topics | jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   199  100   199    0     0  14930      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 15307
[
  "Topic_OracleSource2"
]

curl -X GET http://localhost:8081/subjects | jq

[]
```

Nothing shows.  However, performing a curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.avro.v2+json"       -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json"       --data '{"value_schema": "{\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"User\", \"fields\": [{\"name\": \"name\", \"type\": \"string\"}]}", "records": [{"value": {"name": "testUser"}}]}'       "http://localhost:8082/topics/avrotest"
```

creates the subject:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8081/subjects | jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    18  100    18    0     0   2020      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2250
[
  "avrotest-value"
]
```

As far as I know, doing it this way isn't recommended as topics are created on the fly and not pre-created in a controlled environment.

2. The reason this question comes about is that it seems the subject `'topicName-value/key'` pair is needed to create streams for the topic inside KSQL.

Without subject, I can only see data coming across with the avro-based connector created but can't further perform transformation using ksql stream and table.

Comment: If one of the answers below addressed your question, please mark it as Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

`kafka-topics` only interacts with Zookeeper and Kafka. It has no notion of the existence of a Schema Registry.

The process that creates the Avro schema / subject is the Avro Serializer configuration via the producer. If a Kafka Connect source is configured with the AvroConverter, it'll register a schema itself upon getting data, so you should not need curl, assuming you are satisfied with the generated schema

To my knowledge, there's no way to prevent KSQL from auto-registering a schema in the registry.

> seems the subject 'topicName-value/key' pair is needed to create streams for the topic inside KSQL.

If you want to use Avro, yes. But, no not "needed" for other data formats KSQL supports

> can't further perform transformation using ksql stream and table.

You'll need to be more explicit about why that is. Are you getting errors?

Comment: What I ended up doing was clearing all metadata for the environment and used curl to recreate the connector.  Curl seems to only allow json format but I embedded avro as part of the properties file like so:

Comment: Kafka Connect and the schema registry API only accept JSON, yes

Comment: Ultimately, the idea is to:

Load a connector (Oracle) > create a Topic > KSQL manipulation with pure AVRO as the standard formatting.  Has anyone been successful?

1. load a connector (which with confluent load also creates the topic.  Ex: confluent load Connector_OracleSource_TABLE1 -d source_oracle_TABLE1.properties)
----------
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @source_oracle_TABLE1.properties http://localhost:8083/connectors
----------

Comment: properties (avro):

{
  "name": "Connector_OracleSource_TABLE1",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "topic.prefix": "Topic_OracleSource_TABLE1",
//
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
  }
}

curl was used with json but the body properties file as avro which seems to work but not sure implications?!

Comment: This time the subject gets created: 
--------
curl -X GET http://localhost:8083/connectors | jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    53  100    53    0     0   2960      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3117
[
  "Connector_OracleSource_TABLE1"
]

Comment: curl -X GET http://localhost:8081/subjects | jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    55  100    55    0     0    930      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   948
[
  "Topic_OracleSource_TABLE1-value"
]
it also creates the topic on the fly without using kafka-topics.  Not sure if this is the right way of doing it?

kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2182 --list
Topic_OracleSource_TABLE1

Comment: After which I was able to create the stream for the topic.

ksql> create stream STREAM_Topic_OracleSource_TABLE1 WITH (kafka_topic='Topic_OracleSource_TABLE1', value_format='AVRO');

 Message
----------------
 Stream created
----------------

And seeing data coming in after a database update.

Comment: sorry new to posting here so a bit convoluted including all the technical stuff.  Was going edit the original post but looks out of place with new info.

Comment: I don't typically use Confluent cli, but 1) your properties are still JSON. Avro is not human readable. 2) Kafka Connect will automatically create topics, but this is not recommended in production because topics have default properties defined by the broker 3) Avro schema is also populated automatically from the producer in the registry. For Kafka Connect source connectors, I'd say this is okay because you can't be too sure what schema will be created by the connector 4) I would use console consumer, not KSQL while debugging

Comment: Thanks much cricket_007!  Very helpful for the next steps.

Answer (score 0):

> When `kafka-topics` is used to create topics, does this also create the associated subjects for "topicName-value", etc.?

No, the subjects are not created automatically.  (`kafka-topics` today doesn't even allow you to pass an Avro schema.)

Might be worth a feature request?

Comment: Feature request to Apache or Confluent would patch said script?

Comment: This would be a feature request for Confluent because Apache Kafka's functionality does not include a schema registry, hence AK will not accept a patch to improve its own `kafka-topics.sh`.

Comment: Nice answer of yours btw. :-)

Comment: Thanks Michael and cricket_007!  How does feature request work for a potentially commercial function with Confluent? :)

Comment: @HTL I guess it would require a PR against `TopicCommand` wrapper class that accepts a schema registry URL - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka/blob/master/bin/kafka-topics.sh